# A question based on basic enumerative combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

If in a company there are 250 employees.

If it is given that if you choose any two distinct employees A and B then there exists at least one language that A can speak but B cannot and also there exists at least one another language that B can speak but A cannot.

Then to satisfy this what are the minimum number of languages in the universe.

Comment: You can do this with 10 language as ${10 \choose 5}$ = 252, I will think about how to prove 9 is not possible and why everyone speaking the same number of language will optimize the result.

Comment: See Sperner's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^9=512$ possible subsets of 9 languages labeled {$1,2,...,9$}.

Now consider all subsets without $9$, there are $256$ such subsets.
And for any such subset S, we can generate a tuple {$S, S\cup{9}$} thus giving us all $512$ subsets. Note that any two tuple do not share any common elements.

Since each tuple form a chain under $\subset$ ordering, we can only pick at most one element to assign, because if both are assigned to two people $A$ and $B$ then those two people violate the rule.

This leaves us only 256 values to assign.

However consider the 8 tuples generated by the following $S$s:
$S_1=${$1$}
$S_2=${$1,2$}
$S_3=${$1,2,3$}
...
$S_8=${$1,2,...,8$}

Since $S_1$,...,$S_8$ from a chain under $\subset$ ordering, we can only pick one out of them and $S_1\cup{9}$,...,$S_8\cup9$ form a chain under $\subset$ ordering, we can only pick one out of them as well. This means we can pick at most two elements out of the 8 tuples.

Furthermore, consider the following 3 tuples generated by $S$s:
$S_9=${$2$}
$S_{10}=${$2,3$}
$S_{11}=${$2,3,4$}

For similar reasons we can only pick at most two elements out of the three tuples.

This leaves us only $249$ options which are not enough for $250$ people.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 10 languages, then the number of sets of 5 languages is 10 choose 5, which is 252, which exceeds 250. So you could have 250 people, each knowing 5 languages, no two knowing the same 5 languages, in which case for each member of each pair of people there's be a language that member can speak that the other can't.

Now all you have to do is see that 9 languages aren't enough.

Comment: Can you please complete the proof by proving that it is not possible in case of 9.

Comment: Can you? Can you put any work into the problem yourself, at all?

Comment: I had already reached to this point.

Comment: Next time you post a question, please include everything you know about the answer. That way, neither of us will waste our time.

Comment: sorry gerry ..I should have told my exact problem..but I thought that people will enjoy solving it from beginning.